# SOAP Server was unable to process request

Tags: soap, fault

I have a problem about SOAP request.I want to explain what am I doing.
This is my SOAP request.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
       <web:GetWeather>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <web:CityName>Istanbul</web:CityName>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <web:CountryName>Turkey</web:CountryName>
       </web:GetWeather>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Endpoint : http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx

WSDL link : http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?WSDL

Also this is my code.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        // Create SOAP Connection
        SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory
                .newInstance();
        SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory
                .createConnection();

        // Send SOAP Message to SOAP Server
        String url = "http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?WSDL";
        // SOAPMessage soapResponse =
        SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(createSOAPRequest(),
                url);

        // Process the SOAP Response
        printSOAPResponse(soapResponse);
        soapConnection.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error occurred while sending SOAP Request to Server");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest() throws Exception {
    MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
    SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

    String serverURL = "http://www.webserviceX.NET/";

    SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
    envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("web", serverURL);

    // SOAP Body
    SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
    SOAPElement soapElement = soapBody.addChildElement("GetWeather", "web");
    SOAPElement soapElement1 = soapElement.addChildElement("CityName",
            "web");
    soapElement1.addTextNode("Istanbul");
    SOAPElement soapElement2 = soapElement.addChildElement("CountryName",
            "web");
    soapElement2.addTextNode("Turkey");

    MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
    headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", serverURL + "GetWeather");
    soapMessage.saveChanges();
    return soapMessage;
}

/**
 * Method used to print the SOAP Response
 */
private static void printSOAPResponse(SOAPMessage soapResponse)
        throws Exception {
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory
            .newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    Source sourceContent = soapResponse.getSOAPPart().getContent();
    System.out.print("\nResponse SOAP Message = ");
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
    transformer.transform(sourceContent, result);
}}
```

As a result, I got "Server was unable to process.Procedure or function 'getWeather' expects parameter '@CountryName', which was not supplied."

What does it mean ? Why am I taking this exception ?

Any suggestion about solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the variable `serverUrl` as both the HTTP server URL and as the XML namespace name.  They are close but not exactly the same.  The namespace name is `http://www.webserviceX.NET` but your server URL is `http://www.webserviceX.NET/` (notice the trailing slash).  The string for an XML namespace must be an exact match to the namespace name in the schema.

Recommend you create a separate variable for the namespace (or just inline it):

```
   String serverURL = "http://www.webserviceX.NET/";

   SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
   envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("web", "http://www.webserviceX.NET");
   ...
```

With this change, your code works for me.

Comment: Thank for reply.I changed my code as your answer and it works.I miss out the slash I couldn't see.I am using SoapUI for some property.Do you recommed any tools about web service ?

Comment: I also use SoapUI.  It is very helpful.  You might try Apache CXF wsdl2java (codegen).  It's not necessarily better than what you are doing, but it is another approach to consider.   Also, if you have another Java/SOAP question, do not forget to tag as "Java".  There are many more Java followers than SOAP followers

Comment: Thanks for everything.This information is very helpful for me.Also, I am newbie and I will learn how can I use stackovverflow efficiently.I will note your suggestion.